# Watson Conversation autogenerate Android app - 'Unknown pattern character 'X''

Tags: android, json, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I'm using the auto generated example from IBM Watson Mobile App, but when i tried to run it, it shows an error in the following part of code. I found similar errors around SO, but i think this is another one different.

```
public ServiceCall<MessageResponse> message(String workspaceId, MessageRequest request) {
Validator.isTrue((workspaceId != null) && !workspaceId.isEmpty(), "'workspaceId' cannot be null or empty");

RequestBuilder builder = RequestBuilder.post(String.format(PATH_MESSAGE, workspaceId));
builder.query(VERSION_PARAM, versionDate);
if (request != null) {
  //the error shows here
  builder.bodyJson(GsonSingleton.getGson().toJsonTree(request).getAsJsonObject());
} else {
  builder.bodyJson(new JsonObject());
}
return createServiceCall(builder.build(), ResponseConverterUtils.getObject(MessageResponse.class));
}
```

The following is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin:'base'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ibm.watson_conversation"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        manifestPlaceholders = ['appIdRedirectScheme': android.defaultConfig.applicationId]
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        warning 'InvalidPackage'
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ('com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android:core:[2.0.0,3.0.0)')
    compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:conversation:3.8.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed in 3.9.0.

You just need to update the dependency version to be `3.9.1`:

```
compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:conversation:3.9.1'
```